# Correspondence between Hoelder cocycles and Hoelder potential functions for noncompact negatively curved manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\tilde{M}$ be the universal cover of a pinched\ negatively curved manifold $M$ and $\Gamma=\pi_{1}(M)$ its fundamental group and $\partial \Gamma =\partial \tilde{M}$ its Gromov boundary.
When $M$ is compact Francois Ledrappier showed a bijective correspondence between Hoelder cocycles $c: \Gamma \times \partial \Gamma \to \mathbb{R}$ and zero pressure Hoelder continuous functions $F:T^{1}M\to \mathbb{R}$ on the unit tangent bundle.
(Page 105 of [Structure au bord des variétés à courbure négative](http://www.numdam.org/item/TSG_1994-1995__13__97_0/), Séminaire de théorie spectrale et géométrie, Grenoble 1994–1995, (1995), 97–122.)

The correspondence assigns each $F$ the associated weighted Busemann cocycle.

My question: is there such a correspondence if instead of being compact $M$ is assumed only to have finite Gibbs measure? How about if in addition $M$ is assumed to have finite volume? One can of course still assigns each $F$ the associated weighted Busemann cocycle but it is far from clear to me that all Hoelder cocycles are obtained this way.